# Is Helm a dead god during Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Since Horde of the Dragon Queen starts in the year [1489](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/1489_DR) and [Helm was slain in 1384](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Helm#Death), it seems he should still be dead later on.  I know a lot of the dead deities were brought back during the Sundering but I haven't been able to find a lot of definitive information on the matter.

A player of mine playing a Lawful Neutral cleric of war wanted to choose him as their deity of choice, but we can't seem to figure out if he's dead or not during Hoard of the Dragon Queen.

Is Helm a dead god during Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Helm is alive during the events of the campaign

Page 294 of the Player's Handbook lists Helm in the deity pantheon for the Forgotten Realms. Based purely from this, I think it's fair to assume that Helm, along with the other dead deities who are listed on the pantheon, are resurrected as far as any of the 5e published adventures are concerned.

Additionally, Ed Greenwood and Robert B. Marks [did an AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/2zl2l0/we_are_ed_greenwood_and_robert_b_marks_ask_us/cpjzb8t/) on reddit a while ago, where Greenwood confirmed that Helm has been resurrected, but the exact mechanism, at least at the time of the AMA, hadn't been fleshed out yet. Specifically, he said:

> Helm: Yes. The story? Don't know. Yet.

I do not really keep up with the published storyline of the Forgotten Realms, but based only on some quick research it would appear that [The Sentinel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786964596) by Troy Denning includes a Chosen of Helm as one of the main characters. The book takes place in the year 1486.

With all of this combined, it's pretty much certain as far as I can tell that Helm was indeed resurrected during the events of the Second Sundering and would still be around in 1489 for the events in Hoard of the Dragon Queen.

Comment: I know Ed is the original creator of FR, but what is his current role with regards to the setting?  Is he currently a writer for Wizards?  I guess what I'm asking is, how authoritative is his response?

Comment: @LegendaryDude I'm not entirely sure. Like I said, I don't really keep up with the published storylines very much. But I did find that Ed Greenwood authored the sixth [book of The Sundering series](https://www.amazon.com/Herald-Sundering-Book-VI/dp/078696460X) so he is definitely still involved with the storyline of the Realms to some extent.

Comment: Either way I think your answer is fine.  I wasn't criticizing your use of him as a credible source (he certainly *is* credible to some degree), simply asking for my own academic purposes. :)

Comment: Ed Greenwood does still work for/with WotC, publishing a FR novel as recently as 2016. Also, I'm pretty sure that Helm is described in the Sword Coast Adventurer Guide, which might detail how he came back.